# AVCam not in fullscreen

Tags: ios, border, fullscreen, avcam

I've integrated AVCam in my iOS app. The problem is in iPhone 4 the preview frame isn't fullscreen, it has empty side borders...

How can I solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: do you know how to save also image with the same size as preview?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to use the `videoGravity` property of the `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer`.

Take a look to the [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer/videoGravity). You need to use: `AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill`

Edit:

Based on that the solution founded by the asker is:

```
- (void)setSession:(AVCaptureSession *)session {
    ((AVPlayerLayer *)[self layer]).videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
    ((AVPlayerLayer *)[self layer]).bounds = ((AVPlayerLayer *)[self layer]).bounds;
    [(AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *)[self layer] setSession:session];
}
```

Comment: i fixed it but after take a photo photo has the same size as view had

Comment: But the question is about the preview frame. Please make your own question.

Comment: @dcorbatta just created http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25685179/avcam-full-screen-image-capture

Comment: @dcorbatta do you know why video capture is not happening at full screen even though the camera preview is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34704032/swift-video-records-at-one-size-but-renders-at-wrong-size. thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Fixed it with the following method in AVCamPreviewView.

```
- (void)setSession:(AVCaptureSession *)session {
    ((AVPlayerLayer *)[self layer]).videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
    ((AVPlayerLayer *)[self layer]).bounds = ((AVPlayerLayer *)[self layer]).bounds;
    [(AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *)[self layer] setSession:session];
}
```

Comment: if your self answer was based in my answer, why my answer isn't the correct one?

Comment: cause you didn't have the solution. will mark yours as the correct one, don't worry. :)

Comment: Thanks, no problem. :) I edited my answer to include your result.